# lose the last element of the array in for loop

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

When I execute this code, the last element of the array is lost or why? Why does this happen, will it be because it is an asynchronous function?
[image: console log]

```
async  getRow(){
  const user =  firebase.auth().currentUser
var itemsRef =  Metodos.getRef().child('Amigos/'+user.uid);
 itemsRef.on('value', async (snapshot) =>{

  let items =  [];

  childs = snapshot.val();
  for(child in childs){
    local = await Metodos.getLocal('-Ky7eG2rueIq47GUa7v5');
    firebase.database().ref().child('usuario/'+child).on('value',  (snap) =>{
    datos =  snap.val();

         items.push({
        nombre: datos.nombre,
        imagen: datos.imagen

      })


   })



  }
  this.setState({
    amigos: items
  })



});



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look clearly on your pic, there are actually 5 elements in your object.

Just when you `console.log` it there was 4 elements, and Chrome take snapshot of that object so showed `(4) [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]`.

After that snapshot taken it won't change, but you can see the current value in expanded area.